# How to match git conflict markers with %

Tags: vim, vi

In vi and vim, `%` can be used to find a matching symbol e.g.:

```
/**              <- With the cursor on / ...
 * Some comment
 *
 ...
 *
 */              <- % moves the cursor to the / on this line
```

This works with matching `{}`, `()` `[]` pairs, and also works with c-conditionals like `#ifdef`.

Is there a setting to make this work with git [conflict markers](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging)?

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby

def hello
<<<<<<< HEAD         <- With the cursor on this line
  puts 'hola world'
=======
  puts 'hello mundo'
>>>>>>> mundo        <- % moves the cursor to this line
end
```

Can (and how) vi and/or vim be configured to do that?

Answer (score 2):

In your startup files (eg $HOME/.vimrc) you can add:

```
packadd! matchit
let b:match_words = '<<<<<<<:=======:>>>>>>>'
```

`packadd!` enables the optional plugin, and `match_words` specifies the match pattern.  Note that this will override any previous assignment of match_words, and this sort of thing is typically better suited to store in a filetype plugin.  Adding those two lines directly in the main startup file should work, but may not be the best solution.  (eg, if you're merging a file whose type is recognized, the filetype plugins may override the setting of match_words)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are actually talking about Vim (which makes this configurable) and not vi (which doesn't).

The functionality is documented under `:help %`:

```
%           Find the next item in this line after or under the
            cursor and jump to its match. |inclusive| motion.
            Items can be:
            ([{}])      parenthesis or (curly/square) brackets
                        (this can be changed with the
                        'matchpairs' option)
            /* */       start or end of C-style comment
            #if, #ifdef, #else, #elif, #endif
                        C preprocessor conditionals (when the
                        cursor is on the # or no ([{
                        is following)
            For other items the matchit plugin can be used, see
            |matchit-install|.  This plugin also helps to skip
            matches in comments.
```

From there, you can follow the `'matchpairs'` tag to `:help 'matchpairs'`, which won't help you because you can only add pairs of single characters like `<:>`.

You can then follow the promising `matchit-install` tag, which should put you on the right path.

Try harder.

Comment: I really like this answer (as with nearly all @romainl vi/vim answers).  Except for the final two words.  They could be read as encouragement I guess; but in my part of the world nowadays, it's more often used as denigration.  If I manage to soothe my inner battered child, I will return and click upvote.